# Symfony2 and Doctrine: One to Many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am writing an application in Symfony2 and Doctrine. Here's all the codes that might be necessary:

https://gist.github.com/3440325

This code block works fine and creates the relationship correctly:

```
        $twitter->setUser($user);
        $skype->setUser($user);
```

Working correctly means it creates a row in the users table and inserts the correct user id in the handles table.

Where as, this code block doesn't work as expected:

```
$user->addHandle($skype);
$user->addHandle($twitter);
```

It successfully inserts all the entries but can't insert the correct user id in the handles table. As a matter of fact, the user_id column remains empty.

What is going wrong here? Am I missing something? Is my expectation incorrect or there is some bug some where?

-- Masnun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship, you need to set referenced entities on both sides synchronously.

```
public function addHandle(\WeCodePHP\HomeBundle\Entity\Handle $handles)
{
    $this->handles[] = $handles;
    $handles->setUser($this);
}
```

Otherwise doctrine won't guess what a handle belongs to.